# Get discounted price within custom plugin from another WooCommerce plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I've developed a custom plugin for Wordpress / WooCommerce that is essentially listing out a wishlist of products. One thing I can't work out is how to retrieve the price processed by all hooks / filters added by other plugins: [**Woocommerce Role pricing (light)**](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-role-pricing/).

I have [**Woocommerce Role pricing (light)**](https://fr.wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-role-pricing/) installed and I would like to get the discounted price based on the user role. So programmatically get the discounted price in the context of the plugin I'm building.

Instantiating the product via `WC_Product` works for the single full price only.

ie:

```
$wooProduct = new WC_Product( $val->product_id );
$price = $wooProduct->get_price();
//^^ the above price is wrong and not discounted.
```

In context of what I'm building:

```
// Loop over products / Populate with quantity 0 if no quantity or entry found on existing product.
foreach ($products as $key => $val) {

    $wooProduct = new WC_Product( $val->product_id );

    $price = $wooProduct->get_price();
    //$price is wrong here and not discounted by role pricing light

    $name = $wooProduct->post->post_title;
    $id = $wooProduct->post->ID;
    $url = get_permalink ($id);

    $tmpProducts [] = array(
        "product_id"=>$val->product_id,
        "item_id"=> isset($userOrderProducts[$val->product_id]["item_id"]) ? $userOrderProducts[$val->product_id]["item_id"] : NULL,
        "title" => $wooProduct->post->post_title,
        "url" => get_permalink ($id),
        "price" => $wooProduct->get_price(),
        "qty" => isset($userOrderProducts[$val->product_id]["quantity"]) ? intVal($userOrderProducts[$val->product_id]["quantity"]) : 0,
    );
}
```